# How to place figure via environment while keeping placement intact?

Tags: floats, environments

I'm using the following code to simplify figure creation and referencation.

```
\newenvironment{figcontext}[1]{%
\newcommand{\thefig}{#1}%
\newcommand{\crefsub}[1]{\cref{\thefig}.##1}%
\newcommand{\Crefsub}[1]{\Cref{\thefig}.##1}%
}{}

\newenvironment{cfig}[1]{%
\begin{figcontext}{#1}%
\begin{figure}[h!tb]% only 'H' is respected
\centering%
}{%
\label{\thefig}%
\end{figure}%
\end{figcontext}%
}
```

When replacing all my figures with the `cfig` environment, most figures where moved to separate pages *far* away from their original position in the source code. Why is figure placement (apparantly) affected by the surrounding environment? How can I fix this behaviour without losing the flexibility of `figure` completely?

Comment: If I were you, I'd give the environment an optional argument which allows me to change the placement of the `figure`-environment. Also, could you please make your code snippet a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050)? Why do you even need that environment? Only to change the default placement of figures? There are better solutions to do that, if that's the case.

Comment: No, the default placement of figures is no priority and should even be handled by an optional argument, as you say. Right now I can not reproduce the behaviour in a small MWE. Main reason for this environment is to reduce code lines (`\centering`, `\label`) and making custom commands available in the caption for referencing named objects in a big diagram (`crefsub`). E.g. "Figure 1.b", whereas "b" is simply a character in the picture and not a generated label.

Comment: Examples which don't show the problems aren't MWE. But if you don't have p in the option list then one large figure can force all following figures to the end.

Comment: If your previous figures did not have `[tbh]` as option then the change in position is unrelated to your surrounding environment just simply that you have changed the position argument to `[tbh]` (which as Ulrike indicates is very restrictive and quite likely to send all figures to the end of the document)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I stumbled upon the `\thefig`, too. It isn't the number of the figure (this would be `\thefigure`) but the argument passed to `cfig`. He just uses that macro because the argument isn't allowed to be used in the `\endcfig`-part.

Comment: @Skillmon bad name to use! `\thefig` is pre-allocated for use by `\newcounter{fig}` but yes OK. I'll delete that comment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes that seems to be the root of the problem! I have a *lot* of figures in my document. Hence, introducing unnecessary restrictions on the placement lead to the a huge portion of the figures being pushed to the end. You might consider converting this to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have p in the option list then one large figure can force all following figures to the end. As an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[thb!] %compare with [thb!p]
\rule{1cm}{0.98\textheight}
\caption{blub}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[thb!]
blbl
\caption{blub}
\end{figure}

\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to enclose every figure in your whole document into your `cfig` environment, you could as well just redefine the `figure`-environment. Also you don't have to enclose `\crefsub` and `\Crefsub` inside of the environment, they can be defined globally (and might just use `fig.~\thefigure` instead of `\cref`). I don't know whether these changes do have an impact on your placement issue.

I would do the proposed changes like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

% for MWE
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{cleveref}

%\newcommand{\crefsub}[1]{fig.~\thefigure.#1}% without using cref
%\newcommand{\Crefsub}[1]{Figure~\thefigure.#1}% without using cref
\newcommand{\crefsub}[2][\myfiglabel]{\cref{#1}.#2}% with using cref
\newcommand{\Crefsub}[2][\myfiglabel]{\Cref{#1}.#2}% with using cref

\let\figurebak\figure
\let\endfigurebak\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}[2][tbhp]{
    \def\myfiglabel{#2}%
    \begin{figurebak}[#1]%
        \centering%
}{%
        \label{\myfiglabel}%
    \end{figurebak}%
}


\begin{document}

\blindtext[1]

\blindtext[1]

\blindtext[1]

\begin{figure}{fig:label}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=1.5]
        \draw [help lines, <->]  (0,0) -- (6.5,0) node{a};
        \draw [help lines, ->] (0,-1.1) -- (0,1.1) node{b};
        \draw [green,domain=0:2*pi] plot (\x, {(sin(\x r)* ln(\x+1))/2});
        \draw [red,domain=0:pi] plot (\x, {sin(\x r)});
        \draw [blue, domain=pi:2*pi] plot (\x, {cos(\x r)*exp(\x/exp(2*pi))});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{caption to my fig. Please note \Crefsub{a} and \crefsub{b}}
\end{figure}

See \cref{fig:label} as well as \crefsub[fig:label]{a}.

\blindtext[1]

\blindtext[1]

\blindtext[1]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I would still place the definition of `\crefsub` in the environment to provoke an error if it is used without the proper context. Also, I dislike overwriting standard LaTeX entities, as this might lead to confusion among readers and other subtle problems.

Comment: @MichaelHoff it would still throw an error because `\myfiglabel` is not defined outside of the environment.

Comment: Good point, the same argument applies for `\myfiglabel`. Might even be the better solution.

Comment: @MichaelHoff I really think it is. I tweaked the `\.refsub` commands a little bit, so they become more useful (this way you can use them outside of the environments as well). See my edit!